# What is a smart way to change this query (returning n records) so that it returns only the record having the latest date value?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am not so into database and I have the following problem with this query that have to return only the record having the latest date value.

This is my actual query:

```
SELECT MCPS.id AS series_id,
        MD_CD.market_details_id AS market_id,
        MD_CD.commodity_details_id AS commodity_id,
        MD.market_name AS market_name,
        MCPS.price_date AS price_date,
        MCPS.avg_price AS avg_price,
        CU.ISO_4217_cod AS currency, 
        MU.unit_name AS measure_unit, 
        CD.commodity_name_en,
        CN.commodity_name 
FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series AS MCPS
INNER JOIN MeasureUnit AS MU ON MCPS.measure_unit_id = MU.id
INNER JOIN Currency AS CU ON MCPS.currency_id = CU.id
INNER JOIN MarketDetails_CommodityDetails AS MD_CD ON MCPS.market_commodity_details_id = MD_CD.id
INNER JOIN MarketDetails AS MD ON MD_CD.market_details_id = MD.id
INNER JOIN CommodityDetails AS CD ON MD_CD.commodity_details_id = CD.id
INNER JOIN CommodityName AS CN ON CD.id = CN.commodity_details_id
INNER JOIN Languages AS LN ON CN.language_id  = LN.id
WHERE MD.id = 4
AND CD.id = 4 
AND LN.id=1
```

It returns n records. I have to change it in such a way that it should return only the one having the latest value of the **price_date** field.

The original query returns something like this:

```
series_id            market_name                     price_date        avg_price           commodity_name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                    Tambacounda Market N1           05/10/2017        20,15               Red onion                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
6                    Tambacounda Market N1           12/09/2017        18,94               Red onion                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
7                    Tambacounda Market N1           20/09/2017        28,63               Red onion
```

And the modified query have to return only this record:

```
7                    Tambacounda Market N1           20/09/2017        28,63               Red onion
```

That is the one having the latest **price_date** field value (the most recent price)

What could be a smart way to do it?

Comment: Do you need just one record from whole table or top record with latest date from every set of data? Kindly share sample data and desired output.

Comment: Add `ORDER BY price_date DESC LIMIT 1` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, often when questions like this are asked in this forum, the OP is usually looking for something like this:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM market_commodity_price_series x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT measure_unit_id 
            , currency_id 
            , market_commodity_details_id
            , MAX(price_date) price_date
         FROM market_commodity_price_series 
        GROUP 
           BY measure_unit_id
            , currency_id
            , market_commodity_details_id
     ) y
    ON y.measure_unit_id = x.measure_unit_id
   AND y.currency_id = x.currency_id
   AND y.market_commodity_details_id = x.market_commodity_details_id
   AND y.price_date = x.price_date;
```